# Google Play Store: New SMS permissions policy and form. (Removing permissions completely)

Tags: android

My Android application has been removed from the Play Store because it previously used SMS_READ permission to auto-fill OTPs. Instead of implementing the SMS mechanism for verification, I have decided to remove all SMS permissions from my application. However, Google does not have this as an option while re-uploading the application.

I have tried to file for an exception, however, I am not receiving a response from the support team. I have also tried re-uploading the app while selecting one of the choices in the SMS permission form, while explaining the situation. Once again, the app was removed.

I would like to know how to proceed with uploading the application and having it stay on the PlayStore. It seems that the Google Support team does not accept that all the permissions have been removed.

Comment: Maybe the reason if your old app in beta or alpha test please cross check update if already

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem . I think you forget to remove all SMS_READ related Permissions search whole code once again for permissions .You can run below command to search

```
grep -r 'android.permission.READ_SMS'
```

If you find any occurance of this permission remove that and try to upload apk again in playstore .SMS permission related checks will disappear automatically.


Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

I also face same issue and i fixed it by adding below code to my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
```

After updating version name and version code with this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Shivam Rawat , If this answer is helpful for you then can you please help me to get privilege into this community. Thanks in Advanced.